# How to display records from database in servlet and jsp

Tags: java, servlets

I want to fetch records of mysql database table but using servlet class and display through jsp page please anyone can help me. 
Thank you in adv.

Comment: What....have....you....tried?

Comment: what exactly u mean??????????

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0):

A JSP page also create a Servlet class internally by the web sever

Comment: Thank you but can you give me example..?

Answer (score 0):

why are you using servlet and jsp both for this task , even though you can use just jsp for all that.You can use jsp tags.JSTL also good option to handle with database.
Include below library in your jsp file.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
```